# How to save projects on replit.com?

Tags: python

I have coded a python program on replit.com but when I ran it and closed the window, thinking it autosaved, it did not save at all.
If there are ways to recover the project, please let me know.

Comment: Why not copy and paste the code to a local file?

Comment: @mkrieger what is a local file?

Comment: A file on your computer.

Comment: @mkrieger how do I create a .py file on my computer? Do i have to use another  application to run the file on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

To save your code, you can create a local file on your computer.

Copy and paste your code onto a file on your computer to save your code.